# trying to separate DHCP and Static

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

As a small business, we aim to host our own onsite email server by obtaining a static IP from our ISP. The ISP provided us with a router capable of both Static and DHCP. Currently, the Cox cable is linked to the modem, the modem is connected to their router (static/DHCP), and their router is connected to our router.

To enhance security, I want to segregate these components. If someone gains access to the first router, which is more exposed to the external environment due to the static IP, I want to ensure that they do not automatically have access to the second router and the devices connected to it. If this setup is not sufficiently secure, I welcome suggestions on the best approach to implement this separation, ensuring that the static IP is dedicated solely to the email server while keeping DHCP traffic isolated.

Comment: Put a VLAN capable switch immediately in front of the ISP router and have 2 VLANs that are separated.

Comment: Don't assume that a static IP is any more dangerous than a dynamically assigned public address.  changing a static IP is not generally more difficult than changing a dynamic one if your address is under attack and you'd like to change it. in general changing addresses is not really a viable strategy for dealing with attacks, especially if you have any domains registered that point to your servers. Additionally, someone who has "taken control" of your exterior router will definitely have the ability to send/read traffic emitted from the internal router. nothing you can do changes that.

Comment: cont. so, you need a firewall on your interior router configured to not trust the exterior router for much. thats about all you can do with a single line connection.

Comment: How about putting a VLAN switch right after first router as John's mentioned? or is there a way that ISP can do this separation without adding a new internet service?